# How to set up auto login for user in Spring Boot after user registration using bcrypt, getting Bad Credentials error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, bcrypt

I have a question regarding how I can automatically log in a user after it has registered with my Spring Boot app. The user's password is saved into the MySQL DB using Bcrypt.

This is a method I have to properly create and save a new user, and it seems to work fine :

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

public User save(User user, Role role) {
    user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    user.setRoles(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(role)));
    userRepository.save(user);
    return user;
}
```

This is the method I execute to try to log in a newly created user :

```
 public boolean login(String username, String password) {

    //password is plaintext and is what was POST-ed from the HTML form

    UserDetails userDetails = loadUserByUsername(username);

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken =
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, password, userDetails.getAuthorities());

    authenticationManager.authenticate(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);

    if (usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.isAuthenticated()) {
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
        logger.debug(String.format("Logged in %s successfully!", username));
        return true;
    } else {
        logger.debug(String.format("Failed to login %s", username));
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now, when it hits the line:

```
authenticationManager.authenticate(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
```

it will always complain:

```
00:36:47.635 [http-nio-5000-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Could not complete request
org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
```

I thought this was strange. In my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter , I have these set up:

```
@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userServiceManager).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
}
```

Could someone please let me know if I might have missed anything?
Thanks

Comment: Are you fetching the password as well in `loadUserByUsername(username);` And its not Spring Boot 4! The latest Spring Boot version available is an Milestone release of 2.0 
So it should be Spring Security 4!

Comment: In debug mode did it print any value from this line `userDetails.getAuthorities()` ?

Comment: Hi @ataurRahmanMunna , yes, userDetails.getAuthorities() does return one item in the Collection , a "user" role from the Role table.

Comment: Hi @MohamedSanaulla , yes, the UserDetails object returned by loadUserByUsername does contain the BCrypt encrypted password

Comment: In my case I create a daoAuthProvider `@Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        return authProvider;
    }`

and for authBuilder settings `auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider()).....`

Comment: Thanks @AtaurRahmanMunna , let me try out your suggestion

Comment: Hi @AtaurRahmanMunna , unfortunately, it still doesn't work, I am still getting : org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
 at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.additionalAuthenticationChecks(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:98)
 at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:166)
 at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174)